# In a microservices architecture, should each microservice handle its HTTP headers or should a proxy handle them?

Tags: microservices, http, headers

In a case where having microservices deployed as containers without any orchestration tool, they need to define some HTTP response headers.

A way to achieve it is by having each microservice define their own headers. Another way is by creating an API gateway that attaches them to each microservice response.

For one side, managing them at the microservice level gives a lot of independence as it doesn't make them depend on other components. On the other side, having them at the proxy level frees the microservice of some "non-core" tasks and centralizes it in a network-specific component.

Is there any preferred way to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of headers are you talking about?

Comment: yeah response headers? dont you mean request headers?

Comment: I mean the response headers, that the microservice defines, for example a `Server` header

Comment: You've already articulated the tradeoffs.  The "preferred" way is the way that best orchestrates those tradeoffs.